# A question on how to earn some hats? Also, what will happen to them in 2014?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

I was wondering how some hats are earned, for instance the "Florence Nightingale" and "Full House" hats. Does one need to satisfy the requirement within a single day (I don't see that happening for me) or do I get the "Florence Nightingale" hat if I edit ten posts until the hats disappear in early january?

I was also curious as to what would happen to the hats in 2014? If there is another winter bash next year, will we get our hats back, will we earn the same hats again or will there be new ones?

Comment: To the second question:  nobody around has hats from [Winterbash-2012](http://stackexchange.com/promos/12/winter-bash). Yes, the thing begins anew every year (for as long as SE wants to it to happen). Reusing old hats would not be as fun, even though there is an "old hat" hat (which I think is not actually old).

Comment: @PostNoBills Is the leaderboard for WinterBash-2012 still existent?

Comment: @AhaanRungta As far as I know, it's not.

Comment: @PostNoBills Aw, that's too bad. I'll have to keep some kind of screenshot-like record.